# CKEditor has Empty Value on asp:textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have implemented CKEditor on my Visual Studio 2013 and it has been showed clearly with `asp:TextBox` element.

But somehow while I fetch the value it returns empty.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <asp:TextBox ID="bodyMessageTextBox" runat="server"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_bodyMessageTextBox");
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I fetch with this method;

```
_msemailsetup.BodyMessage = this.bodyMessageTextBox.Text;
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: Check below solution for that and Please accept the ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the data with below code :

Inspect (press f12 on browser) the browser and then check the name of editor

```js
 var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.bodyMessageTextBox.getData();
 _msemailsetup.BodyMessage = editorText ;
```